# Como criar um Mock no Ruby On Rails (CarrierWave) para simular o envio de imagem a um S3 (Cloudinary)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mock

Criei um sistema de criação de projeto com imagem. Minhas imagens são enviadas para o Cloudinary + CarrierWave.

Antes o Teste não quebrava porque eu enviava para o servidor, porém quando eu integrei no Cloudinary o código quebrou.

Acho que sei o que pode ser, mas não sei consertar. Quando ele insere no banco de dados do Cloudinary ele retorna um valor aleatório, como faço para

```
   **within(".asset_project") do
      expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='project.png']")
   end**
```

o TDD ficar correto, pois acho que seja isso.

Segue a imagem dos erros e do código:
[image: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-dasTkpspvKI/VHNl-7pfVRI/AAAAAAAAEt4/L-fNHEwV0ek/s1600/creating_projects_spec.png]

[image: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Ra4_Fe5ufAw/VHNl0g3_THI/AAAAAAAAEto/Gk3nE3lM2RQ/s1600/BDD.png]

Comment: se ele poe um valor aleatório, vc não pode acessar o model e comparar se o que tá na view é o mesmo do model?

Comment: Se entendi a pergunta, você precisa "mockar" uma chamada à uma API externa. É isso?  Se sim, usar a gem WebMock não resolve?

Comment: resolveu a gem! Muito obrigado!